# How to create a powershell shortcut for my python file

Tags: python, powershell, command-prompt

I have just started out with Python, I am trying to get a way to get a shortcut on my Start menu or taskbar that I can click on and it will cause Command Prompt or PowerShell to start my Python file

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question?

Comment: Voting to close: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on http://www.SuperUser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to shortcut properties and add after target:

```
/K python [path\to\your_script.py]
```